# Laravel Passport how to pass the access token to js?

Tags: php, laravel, access-token, api-design, laravel-passport

I would like to ask how can I get back the `accessToken` from current user?
Background: I would like to develop an API that requires authentication of users.

Now, I am able to create the accessToken by:

```
$accessToken = $user->createToken('auth_token')->accessToken;
```

but where do I `$accessToken`? I have done some research on it, and I should not store the `accessToken` on database, I can get back some of the details of current users token.

For example:
I can get back the user token by defining one-to-many relationship

```
$user->tokens->each(function($token){

})
```

but it can only get back the field in `oauth_access_tokens` table, I cannot get back the `accessToken`.

What I would like to do is, get the `accessToken`, and pass it to the frontend js.

I have few questions to ask:

1. is it a proper way to pass the `accessToken` directly from backend to frontend, because I am thinking if someone is able to view the bearer token via dev tools, then user credential will be compromised.
2. how can I get back the access token via token id? or I should not get back the `accessToken` again? Similar to some of the API token service, you can only get the `accessToken` when you create the token, after created the token, you have to store it locally, and the server will not tell you the access token again?

I know I have asked a lot of dumb questions.

Comment: If you are using passport and generated the token, then it automatically created in the database, supposed you ran the migrations. You pass it via JSON response to front end. You can need to purge it when logout, you can get auth user details via token as API based calls token is the only thing to access app.
Get auth user like this
$user = \Passport\Token\Token::find($token)->user();